# 'librtmp.so' for 'libffmpeg.so' not found

Tags: android, streaming, android-videoview, vitamio

i have problem on playing url stream or any other video file using Vitamio.
i tested example video view on Vitamio and same result returned.
i try play this file http://takhtesefid.org/videos/236184163282.mp4
. but that seems same error for other files.
any idea?

```
03-25 01:44:59.194: D/skia(25442): The file input width: 16, height: 16, output width: 16, height: 16, format: 6, prefer size: 0, dither: 0
03-25 01:44:59.199: D/JpgDecHal(25442): jpeg decoder result:0
03-25 01:44:59.308: D/dalvikvm(25442): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 107K, 50% free 2835K/5635K, external 0K/0K, paused 48ms
03-25 01:44:59.354: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): CPU implementer:0x41
03-25 01:44:59.354: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): Serial:0000000000000000
03-25 01:44:59.354: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): CPU architecture:6
03-25 01:44:59.355: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): Hardware:MT6573
03-25 01:44:59.355: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): CPU revision:7
03-25 01:44:59.355: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): CPU variant:0x0
03-25 01:44:59.355: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): CPU part:0xb76
03-25 01:44:59.356: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): Revision:65fb8a00
03-25 01:44:59.356: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): BogoMIPS:668.46
03-25 01:44:59.356: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): Features:swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java
03-25 01:44:59.356: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): Processor:ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
03-25 01:44:59.358: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): CPU architecture: 6
03-25 01:44:59.360: D/Vitamio[Player](25442): GET CPU FATURE: V5TE V6 VFP 
03-25 01:44:59.361: D/dalvikvm(25442): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.playdroid/lib/libvinit.so 0x4051e6b0
03-25 01:44:59.364: D/dalvikvm(25442): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.playdroid/lib/libvinit.so 0x4051e6b0
03-25 01:44:59.370: I/Vitamio[Player](25442): isNativeLibsInited, APP VERSION: ۱, Vitamio Library version: ۱
03-25 01:44:59.374: I/Vitamio[Player](25442): LIB ROOT: /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/
03-25 01:44:59.374: D/dalvikvm(25442): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libstlport_shared.so 0x4051e6b0
03-25 01:44:59.411: D/dalvikvm(25442): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libstlport_shared.so 0x4051e6b0
03-25 01:44:59.411: D/dalvikvm(25442): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libstlport_shared.so 0x4051e6b0, skipping init
03-25 01:44:59.412: D/dalvikvm(25442): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libvplayer.so 0x4051e6b0
03-25 01:44:59.420: D/dalvikvm(25442): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libvplayer.so 0x4051e6b0
03-25 01:44:59.424: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
03-25 01:44:59.424: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
03-25 01:44:59.426: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): LOAD FFMPEG START: /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libffmpeg.so
03-25 01:44:59.430: E/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): LOAD FFMPEG ERROR: Cannot load library: link_image[1993]:    90 could not load needed library 'librtmp.so' for 'libffmpeg.so' (load_library[1135]: Library 'librtmp.so' not found)
03-25 01:44:59.431: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): LOAD VVO START: /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libvvo.9.so
03-25 01:44:59.448: E/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): FIND_NAME_SYM vvo, render_yuv
03-25 01:44:59.448: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): LOAD VVO END: /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libvvo.9.so
03-25 01:44:59.448: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): LOAD VAO START: /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libvao.0.so
03-25 01:44:59.450: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): LOAD VAO END: /data/data/com.test.playdroid/libs/libvao.0.so
03-25 01:44:59.452: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): VPLAYER INIT BEGIN
03-25 01:44:59.452: I/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](25442): Application package name: com.test.playdroid
03-25 01:44:59.456: I/dalvikvm(25442): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
03-25 01:44:59.456: D/dalvikvm(25442): SigQuit + : 0
03-25 01:44:59.464: I/dalvikvm(25442): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-25 01:44:59.465: D/dalvikvm(25442): SigQuit - : 0
```

i try find some librtmp.so file compiled for android from xmbc and other android apps. 
but i don't know how can i use them.
when i copy it into libs folder . there is no change in error.
is there any library that let me play streaming file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sent this problem as bug
https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/121
that seems solved in new commit
https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/commit/e557cea38e4ddc34026c469625a459a04ce32ef8

Answer (score 1):

Please download Vitamio master branch, it's compile ffmpeg with librtmp.

Answer (score 0):

Vitamio - actually latest versions of it can be found at:

```
https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/releases
```

Just head on for 4.2.2, then you will see Download section, and this:

```
**DOWNLOAD**
Source code (zip)
```

or alternatively click here:

> https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/archive/v4.2.2.zip

Master Bundle has not been updated for long time now, all latest fixes are under releases folder :)

Hope it helps, Enjoy.